# I can change the iOS splash screen but I can't change the Android splash screen. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In `Edit>Project Settings>Player`, I am able to set the splash screen for iOS. But when I switch to the Android tab, the option to change the splash screen is greyed out. But I do see that the Mobile Splash Screen is a shared setting between multiple platforms. So I went ahead and set the Mobile Splash Screen in the iOS tab, hoping that it would also reflect in the Android tab since it is a shared setting.

I have tested on both my iOS and Android devices. My splash screen only shows on my iOS device, but not on my Android device.

I do not have either Android Pro or iOS Pro. Just Unity Pro. Correct me if I'm wrong but this can't be a "Pro License" issue right? Given that I can change the iOS settings but not the Android settings.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @golergka I'm using Unity 5.0.1f on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity 5's "splash screen" implementation seems to differ between iOS and Android. I would guess this is either a bug with Unity, or a setting that should be improved on (or greyed out entirely without an iOS Pro license).

The iOS "splash screen" texture you can choose acts as the [iOS app's Launch Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html):

> A launch file or image provides a simple placeholder image that iOS
>   displays when your app starts up. The placeholder image gives users
>   the impression that your app is fast and responsive because it appears
>   instantly and is quickly replaced by the first screen of your app.
>   Every app must supply a launch file or at least one static image.

This launch image appears for a moment before Unity's "Made with Unity" splash appears. The "Made with Unity" splash seems to actually be inserted into the first scene that you load (eg you could have a sound file playing from the start and it will start playing as soon as the "Made with Unity" screen appears); the "splash screen" texture you can choose is just an iOS Launch Image that all apps have to have, and appears before your app actually starts. Being able to change this without iOS Pro seems counterintuitive, since the launch image is supposed to look like the first moments of your app, which is the inserted "Made with Unity" splash.

As of Unity 5.0.1, it's interesting to note that on Android, you get a quick flash of a "Made with Unity" image for like .5 seconds, and then your scene loads, whereas on iOS, "Made with Unity" is inserted into your running scene.

But if you have a Unity iOS Pro license, you'll want to make the splash image resemble your first scene.

So to summarise:

- On iOS, Unity's default splash screen is a solid colour image acting as the iOS launch image, and then Unity adds its own "Made with Unity" splash into your first scene while your scene is running.
- On Android, a mere "Made with Unity" image is shown before your first scene actually loads, and nothing is actually added to your scene.

Perhaps with Android Pro, the splash image you choose would get shown in place of the simple "Made with Unity" image, but to have this be called a "shared setting" without iOS Pro nor Android Pro seems incorrect, something worth filing a report over.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the information. Calling it a "Shared Setting" is a confusion. So basically I need an Android Pro license to be able to show the splash image I'd like to show.